# Restore Previous Version Data from table with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL 2.4 SQL query API.

I have a table with key-columns as (`id` + `version`). There could be multiple values for same `id` but records are made unique by including the `version` column. There is also a column called `delete_flg` which signify whether that `id` + `version` combination is active or deleted at the source. However, if the value for `delete_flg = 'Y'`, it means that this record has been deleted at the source, and hence the latest version just **preceeding** to this particular record version must be selected for loading Target.

**SOURCE**:

```
id | version | name | delete_flg
--------------------------------
10 |   1     | John | N
10 |   2     | Mike | N
10 |   3     | Henry| N
```

**Scenario 1** - Latest record selected (based on version) (since `delete_flg` = 'N'):

Target:

```
id | version | name 
--------------------
10 |   3     | Henry
```

**Scenario 2**: Now consider, next day the last record from yesterday comes as delete (`Y`) -

SOURCE:

```
id | version | name | delete_flg
--------------------------------
10 |   3     | Henry| Y
```

In this case, `version = 3` has been deleted at source (`delete_flg = Y`). Hence, `version = 2` should be selected for the target.

**Target**:

```
id | version | name 
--------------------
10 |   2     | Mike
```

Note that the target has now been set to the record **immediately preceding** the deleted record (i.e. `version` = `2` -> "Mike").

Please advise how to approach the query. Any inputs is appreciated.

Comment: odd approach. would have though v4 would come thru.

Comment: r u getting al records in again when the del = Y is the case? unclear.

Comment: you will get a v4 rec i assume

Comment: actually quite a good question

Comment: Did you manage to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You are not really clear on input, I see 3 options. I chose the 1st one and I present a solution, see the comments I made. If the input is different, you should be able to work out from this as this covers all of them.

Two parts: generation and then query, you can run that with %sql.

I did it this way with enhanced input but it could probably be done with partitionBy and RANK. The crux is the (10,3,...) entries that complicates things.

**Generate data - not for you**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// Option 1
val df_all = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (10, 0, "mark", "N"),
    (10, 1, "john", "Y"),
    (10, 2, "barry", "N"),
    (10, 3, "pete", "N"),
    (10, 3, "pete", "Y"),
    (10, 4, "new pete", "N"),
    (20, 1, "john", "N"),
    (20, 2, "prev barry", "N"),
    (20, 3, "pete", "N"),
    (20, 3, "pete", "Y"),
    (30, 1, "first pete", "N")
)).toDF("id", "v", "n", "d")

// Option 2
val df_at_rest = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (10, 1, "john", "N"),
    (10, 2, "pete", "N"),
    (10, 3, "peter", "N")
)).toDF("id", "v", "n", "d")

// Option 3
val df_delta = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (10, 4, "pete", "Y")
)).toDF("id", "v", "n", "d")

df_all.createOrReplaceTempView("dfa")
df_at_rest.createOrReplaceTempView("dfr")
df_delta.createOrReplaceTempView("dfd")
```

**Query of interest for Option 1**

```
spark.sql(""" select id, v, n  
                           from dfa a, (select id as id1, max(v) as max_v
                                          from dfa 
                                         where d = 'N'
                                         group by id) B
               where a.id = b.id1
                 and a.v = b.max_v
                 and a.d = 'N'
                 and a.id not in (select a.id 
                                    from dfa a, (select id as id2, max(v) as max_v2
                                                   from dfa 
                                                  where d = 'N'
                                               group by id) B
                                   where a.id = b.id2
                                     and a.v = b.max_v2
                                     and a.d = 'Y')
                      union all

                         select id, v, n 
                           from dfa E, (
                            select id2, max(v) as max_v2
                              from dfa, (select id2, max_v2 
                                           from dfa a, (select id as id2, max(v) as max_v2
                                                         from dfa 
                                                        where d = 'N'
                                                      group by id) B
                                          where a.id = b.id2
                                            and a.v = b.max_v2
                                            and a.d = 'Y') C
                             where id = C.id2
                               and v < C.max_v2 
                          group by id2) D
                  where E.id = D.id2
                    and E.v = D.max_v2                          
          """).show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+---+----------+
|id |v  |n         |
+---+---+----------+
|10 |4  |new pete  |
|30 |1  |first pete|
|20 |2  |prev barry|
+---+---+----------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. When v3 gets deleted at the source, they will send only the v3 record with a `delete_flg = 'Y'`. Other unchanged versions are not sent. Consider in the last run my target had v3 data since source had sent v1, v2, v3 with `delete_flag = 'N'`. Hence, i had loaded the max v value record i.e. v3. Now say for today's  execution they sent the v3 record as a delete i.e. `delete_flg = 'Y'`. Hence in the target I need to revert back to v2 record values. If v2 is also sent as deleted (ie Y) we have to revert to v1 and so on.. Hope this clarifies. Pls let me know.

Comment: The heavy lifting is done, give it a try. The question was of course a little unclear.